# Inheriting from a generic abstract class with a concrete type parameter is not enforced in PyCharm

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

**Background**: I am using PyCharm 2019.1 and Python 3.7

**Question**: I would like to create a generic abstract class, such that when I inherit from it and set the generic type to a concrete type, I want the inherited methods to recognize the concrete type and show a warning if the types do not match.

#### Generic ABC with Subclass

```python
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")


class FooGenericAbstract(ABC, Generic[T]):

    @abstractmethod
    def func(self) -> T:
        pass


class Foo(FooGenericAbstract[dict]):  # I am specifying T as type dict

    def func(self) -> dict:  # I would like the return type to show a warning, if the type is incorrect
        pass
```

#### No warning for incorrect type

I would expect an error here, since the return type `list` does not match the concrete type parameter `dict`.

```python
class Foo(FooGenericAbstract[dict]):  # I am specifying T as type dict

    def func(self) -> list:  # Should be a warning here!
        pass
```

Answer (score 8):

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Dict, Generic, List, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class FooGenericAbstract(ABC, Generic[T]):

    @abstractmethod
    def func(self) -> T:
        pass


class Foo(FooGenericAbstract[Dict[str, int]]): 

    def func(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        pass
```

With coc.nvim and python 3.8, mypy 0.770 warns as expected.

I guess maybe you should use type hints instead of built-in types, since mypy cannot recognize the built-in types until now.

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm has very weak support for type hints in general, so always be advised to rely on [the Mypy plugin available in the JetBrains marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11086-mypy).

Your example is one of those cases where explicit annotations silently override the types specified by the base class, even when using the uppercase `List` and `Dict` types from the `typing` module. It raises an error as expected using the Mypy plugin.